# Unity UV map, tint / change color of texture

Tags: unity, textures, uv-mapping

I have an array of vertices with texture coordinates for a UV map in Unity:

```
newUV.Add(new Vector2 (0, 1)); // FACE 1
newUV.Add(new Vector2 (1, 1));
newUV.Add(new Vector2 (1, 0));
newUV.Add(new Vector2 (0, 0));

newUV.Add(new Vector2 (0, 1)); // FACE 2
newUV.Add(new Vector2 (1, 1));
newUV.Add(new Vector2 (1, 0));
newUV.Add(new Vector2 (0, 0));

mesh.uv = newUV.ToArray();
```

It textures my mesh just fine.

How could I go around tinting FACE 1 to a darker color? Let's say the texture is just plain green and I wanted to texture only on FACE 1 to be a darker shade of green.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say the texture is just plain green and I wanted to texture only
>   on FACE 1 to be a darker shade of green.

I think you have 3 possibilities:

- use a second texture lookup to drive different light intensity on different part of the mesh. Perhaps you want to look at [self-illumin shaders](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/shader-SelfIllumFamily.html) built-in in unity. May be that's exactly what you are looking for, if you only want a different light intensity on some area.

Two other way of doing it (probably not suited for your specific case, but useful in more complex scenarios):

- split the mesh into 2 submesh and assign a different material to each submesh (same texture but different shaders of uniform values) => (draw back: you'll probably have an additional draw call unless the mesh can be static/dynamic batched)
- encode some additional data into some unused vertex attributes and use that data inside the shader to apply a darker shading (draw back: memory overhead per vertex: if the mesh is you will waste memory for just darkening a potentially small area)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I am indeed working on implementing lighting on my Voxel world and I think your first proposed solution is the one I'm looking for but I can't figure out exactly what you mean by "use a second texture lookup to drive different light intensity". I understand how Minecraft determines the lighting of a face (a value between 15 and 0 depending on distance from the light source). But I don't understand how I could use the self-illum shader to apply different lighting to different vertices/faces. Are you saying I should apply a second UV map w/ semi transparent texture

Comment: If I'm using a Self-illumin shader, how can I apply UV coordinates for the illumin? I know the mesh can take two UV maps so I figure to use one UV map for the texture and the second UV map for applying different shades using the illumin texture. But how can I tell unity to use the Illumin and not the Base when applying the second UV map.